# Поставити чи положити

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова

Знайома з Вінницької області,завжди говорть- "постав зошит/книжку на стіл"
Я вважаю, що зошит/книжку можна лише положити на стіл.
Тобто, горизонтально - [положити](http://sum.in.ua/s/polozhyty), вертикально-[поставити.](http://sum.in.ua/s/postavyty)

Проте, як правильно говорити, так і не знаю.

Comment: А чому, наприклад, не "покласти"?
"Покладіть зошити на стіл, будь ласка".

Comment: Якщо поставили, а воно впало, зважай положили

Answer (score 6):

Потрібно уважно подивитися значення кожного слова. В тому ж СУМі слово поставити має значення:

> Помістити куди-небудь, розмістити десь.

І приклади:

> В хату увійшла восьмилітня Харитя і поставила коло печі відро
>
> **Поставили** на стіл вареників макітру І пляшку — свашку всіх мирян

Чому книгу не можна поставити на стіл так само як вареники? Очевидно, що тарілка чи пляшка не знаходилися у вертикальному положені. Наведу ще приклад з літератури ("Поринь у книгу" Влада Ковтуненко):

> - Зараз, - він поставив книгу назад на полицю

Щоправда тут не зовсім очевидно в якому положені була книга. В творі "Звір із Лісу":

> Арзент стояв збоку, на його обличчі з’явилася зловісна посмішка, коли
>   вогонь згас він поставив книгу на стіл.

Однак, [словник-антисуржик](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/antisurzhik_pravilna_mova/5-1-0-244) взагалі пише, що "положити" - це суржик, а тому потрібно вживати слово "покласти". Хоч, поки воно є СУМі без приміток, то, я гадаю, його можна вживати.

На мою думку слова "положити" та "покласти" не є абсолютними синонімами і якщо ми заглянемо в СУМ, то знайдемо цьому підтвердження. Однак, гадаю, що два слова можна вживати в значені "помістити/розмістити щось на чомусь".

Comment: Українська граматика 1917 року описує використання префікса по-, в даному випадку, як надання часівникам недоконаним доконаної форми (закінченість): по-білити, по-чорнити, по-просити.
Слово "ставити" можливо можна зрозуміти, як зафіксувати щось у просторі на горизонтальній поверхні в прямому чи переносному значенні.

Answer (score 3):

Пономарів каже, що "ложити" в сучасній мові не використовується — [«Блог проф. Пономарева: "ложимо" чи "кладемо"»](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40640475):

> У сучасній українській літературній мові слова *ложити* немає. З приростками і без них маємо *класти*, *покласти*, *скласти*, *накладати*, *розкладати* тощо.
>
> Наказовий спосіб — *клади*, *поклади*, *кладіть*, *покладіть*.

Comment: Маєте рацію. Однак, мені здається, на запитання це все-таки не зовсім вілповідає: хай ми навіть замінимо «ложити» на «класти», однаково залишається питання, у яких випадках ставлять, а в яких кладуть.

Answer (score 1):

Щодо слова "поставити" - все вірно. "Поставити" походить від "стояти". Можна поставити книгу на полицю, коли вона там дійсно буде "стояти" вертикально.
Я не думаю, що коли ваша знайома каже "постав книгу на стіл", вона має на увазі, що книгу треба якось примостити вертикально, щоб вона так трималась.

Але й "положити" в сучасній мові майже не використовується, рекомендується вживати "покласти".

Тож, вірно буде: "поклади книгу на стіл".

Comment: Це може бути щось діалектне чи розмовне. Як ото «*насипати* борщ» (замість, здавалося б, логічнішого «наливати»). Але плюсанув, суто з логічного погляду Ви безумовно маєте рацію.

Comment: Цей допис виграв би, якби базувався не лише на особистій думці автора, але і містив посилання на авторитетні джерела.

Comment: @Sasha не певен, що борщ логічніше наливати. Тут може мати значення наскільки борщ густий.

Comment: @Yola, я подумав, і тепер згоден з тобою.

Answer (score -2):

http://sum.in.ua/s/postavyty
ПОСТАВИТИ 1, влю, виш; мн. поставлять; док., перех.
8. Помістити куди-небудь, розмістити десь. — Отой стільчик візьми, Христино, — порядкує панич, — та постав серед хати (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 154); В хату увійшла восьмилітня Харитя і поставила коло печі відро (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 13); Під'їхавши до воріт, хлопець сплигнув з коня й одчинив їх. А тоді поставив коня в конюшню, а корову до ясел прив'язав (Андрій Головко, I, 1957, 96); — А це ми конфіскуємо, — каже Яцуба і обома руками бере зі столу Віталиків передавач. — Постав на місце, — перепинила Яцубу Лукія (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 107);
//  Подати на стіл (страви, напої і т. ін.). Поставили на стіл вареників макітру І пляшку — свашку всіх мирян (Леонід Глібов, Вибр., 1957, 211); Ввечері зварила Настя вечерю й поставила перед Гнатом (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 53); Другого дня справили весілля. Цар поставив їм таку гостину, що навіть Поїдайло і Попивайло були задоволені (Три золоті слова, 1968, 125).
Поставити могорич (могорича) кому — почастувати кого-небудь вином, горілкою (за послугу, допомогу і т. ін.). Лаврін знав парубоцький звичай і повів усю парубочу ватагу в шинок. Він поставив їм могорича і вже в згоді з ними вернувся на вулицю (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 313); Упрохає [Клим] писаря та старшину, поставить могорич або одмолотить днів зо три — і Петрика приймуть до волості (Степан Васильченко, I, 1959, 96); Поставити обід кому — почастувати обідом кого-небудь, влаштувати обід для когось. — Зробити поминки я хочу, Поставити обід старцям (Іван Котляревський, I, 1952, 90); Поставити чарку (пляшку і т. ін.) кому — почастувати кого-небудь горілкою, вином. — Ти знаєш, як твого батька упрошував Сафрон у революцію зайти до нього? Він не тільки чарку поставив би Тимофієві (Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 376); — Завгосп спробував був мене підкупити — півлітра якось мені поставив (Юрій Збанацький, Єдина, 1959, 135).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Цей допис містить лише копі-пасту із словникової статті. Кожна відповідь на цьому сайті має містити, власне, відповідь. (1) Вкажіть, який висновок має зробити читач із наведеної цитати. (2) будь ласка, відформатуйте текст, щоб він не виглядав, як стіна тексту без параграфів. (3) при копіюванні тексту зі словника, варто скорочувати кількість прикладів, лишаючи тільки ті, що відповідають порушеній проблемі.

Comment: The user has Unregistered status, отже, навряд чи докладе зусиль до виправлення цього допису, і це значить, що це має зробити хтось інший. Допоки це не зроблено, я голосую за видалення цього допису.